# How divide two numbers in java script

Tags: javascript, numbers, divide

I am facing the issue in division of numbers in java script.

Example:

```
 var x= 2500, var y = 100

 alert(x/y)
```

is showing 25.

I need the answer in  **25.00**  format. What can I do?

When I divide 2536/100, it gives as expected.

Answer (score 14):

You can try [number.toFixed(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
alert( (x/y).toFixed(2) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the toPrecision() method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp
It's a method defined in Number's prototype.
If you want to dynamically retrieve a float number with a specific precision (in your case 2), you can do de following:

```
var x = 2500;
var y = 100;
var res = x/y;
var desiredNumberOfDecimals = 2;
var floatRes = res.toPrecision(String(res).length + desiredNumberOfDecimals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
    alert((x/y).toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 2500;
var y = 100;
alert( (x/y).toFixed(2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to enter x and y as a dollar amount? ie 25.00 and 1.00? if so then use the parseFloat method.

```
var x = 25.00
var y = 1.00
alert(parseFloat(x/y));
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Your answer is not answering the question; Instead, you have changed the question indeed. So, in that case, it's better to tell your opinion/hint as a comment (which you cannot comment right now, cause of your current score). So, Please try to give a related answer, without changing the question conditions (`var x= 2500, var y = 100`)

Answer (score -1):

You need to take a look at number formatting and decimal precision etc.
Look here: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html